# CSS3 selector last-of-type within a wrapper of div items

Tags: css

I've been trying to select the last "cell partner" and also the last cell. `last-of-type` doesn't seem to working for me, if I use `first-of-type` then it selects the first item of cw_partner, I don't know why last-of-type isn't working in my example code:

**HTML :**

```
<div id="listWrapper">
    <div class="cell_wrapper cw_partner">
        <div class="cell partner">
            <div class="listing_picture">
            </div>

            <div class="listing_title">
                TITLE
            </div>

            <div class="listing_description">
                <div class="desc_addr">
                     This cell should NOT BE SELECTED!<br>
                     <br>
                </div>
                <div class="desc_info">
                     <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cell_wrapper cw_partner">
        <div class="cell partner">
            <div class="listing_picture">
            </div>

            <div class="listing_title">
                TITLE
            </div>

            <div class="listing_description">
                <div class="desc_addr">
                     This cell should NOT BE SELECTED!<br>
                     <br>
                </div>
                <div class="desc_info">
                     <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cell_wrapper cw_partner">
        <div class="cell partner">
            <div class="listing_picture">
            </div>

            <div class="listing_title">
                TITLE
            </div>

            <div class="listing_description">
                <div class="desc_addr">
                     This cell partner should be selected<br>
                     <br>
                </div>
                <div class="desc_info">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="cell_wrapper noPartner">
        <div class="cell noPartner">
            <div class="listing_picture" style="">
            </div>

            <div class="listing_title">
                TITLE
            </div>

            <div class="listing_description">
                <div class="desc_addr">
                     <br>
                     <br>
                </div>
                <div class="desc_info">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cell_wrapper noPartner">
        <div class="cell noPartner">
            <div class="listing_picture" style="">
            </div>

            <div class="listing_title">
                TITLE
            </div>

            <div class="listing_description">
                <div class="desc_addr">
                     <br>
                     <br>
                </div>
                <div class="desc_info">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="cell_wrapper noPartner">
        <div class="cell noPartner">
            <div class="listing_picture" style="">
            </div>

            <div class="listing_title">
                TITLE
            </div>

            <div class="listing_description">
                <div class="desc_addr">
                     This cell noPartner should be selected<br>
                     <br>
                </div>
                <div class="desc_info">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#listWrapper {
        width: 300px;
        height: 600px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .cell_wrapper {
        background: #9f9fff;
        height: 70px;
        width: 280px;
    }

    .cell {
        background: #fe9;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    #listWrapper .cw_partner:last-of-type .cell:last-of-type,
    .cell_wrapper:last-child .cell:last-of-type {
        background: red;
    }
```

I also have this on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SxB3M/4/

Answer (score 0):

last-of-type does only work for types (tag names) – to get the last div inside a container for instance. I think what you are trying to do can only be done with Javascript.

**UPDATE:** Adding a simple jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ESUGN/1/

```
$('.cw_partner').last().find('.cell').last().css('background','red');
```

Comment: Hmm, in theory I could change the partners to not use div, but semantically I can't use section. Would <div_partner> be allowed (custom tags)? I don't care much for SEO as it's for sites that will be installed in machines for a kiosk and not a site that should be indexed on Google... though saying that I suppose I could use section, unless there's something better?

Comment: Well, the W3C does not approve of it but HTML5-capable browsers don't care about custom tags. If you have control over the type of browser in your kiosk application, this would be an option. But the cleaner solution would be to either add functionality to to your backend, e.g. additional classes for this case, or to use the DOM with some simple Javascript functions (no need to go full out jQuery).

Comment: Updated my answer to include a simple jQuery solution. Probably overkill and can accomplished with core JS and a few more lines just as well.